# Dynamically Adding child controls to a silverlight textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls, children

Please forgive this stupid question. (I'm originally an ASP.NET programmer.)

I'm trying to add a telerik context menu to a textbox control in the code behind.

Adding it in the xaml is very easy (this works)

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="txtIssues" Width="280" Height="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<telerikNavigation:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
    <telerikNavigation:RadContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu"
            ItemClick="ContextMenuClick">
        <telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Set Vista as Background" />
        <telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Set Beach as Background" />
        <telerikNavigation:RadMenuItem Header="Set Forest as Background" />
    </telerikNavigation:RadContextMenu>
</telerikNavigation:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

However I would like to completely add the the control from c# code and I can't find a why to add a control to a textbox. I've been looking for something like "txtIssues.Children.Add" but there doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First its best you understand that you are not adding a control to the `TextBox`.  The `RadContextMenu.ContextMenu` is not a control it is an [attached property](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Attached-Properties-in-Silverlight.aspx).

Funnily enough the Telerik documentation describes adding a context menu to a textbox in C#.  See [Working with the RadContextMenu](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radcontextmenu-features-working-with-radcontext-menu.html).  Sometimes "RTM" is actually good advice.